# ESLint linting node_modules

Tags: vue.js, eslint, eslintrc, eslintignore

I have been trying all results on google search as a possible solution but without any luck so far.

Whenever I run `npm run vue-cli-service serve --port 1024` on my vue project (created using vue cli) I get errors from `node_modules`

```
4111:10 Type alias 'MergeList' circularly references itself.
    4109 |     @hidden
    4110 |     */
  > 4111 |     type MergeList<O, Path extends List<Key>, O1 extends object, depth extends Depth, I extends Iteration = IterationOf<'0'>> = O extends object ? O extends (infer A)[] ? MergeList<A, Path, O1, depth, I>[] : Pos<I> extends Length<Path> ? OMerge<O, O1, depth> : {
         |          ^
    4112 |         [K in keyof O]: K extends Path[Pos<I>] ? MergeList<O[K], Path, O1, depth, Next<I>> : O[K];
    4113 |     } & {} : O;
    4114 |     /**
```

All errors looks like it is coming simplely from one folder: `ts-toolbelt`. The final result can be seen here: [pastebin](https://pastebin.pl/view/db19a46f)

Here is my `.eslintrc`:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,

  env: {
    node: true,
  },

  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    '@vue/airbnb',
    '@vue/typescript',
  ],

  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", {"devDependencies": true}],
    'import/no-cycle': 'off',
  },

  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    exclude: [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },

  overrides: [
    {
      files: [
        '**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)',
        '**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)'
      ],
      env: {
        jest: true
      }
    }
  ],
};
```

`.eslintignore`

```
node_modules/
public/
bin/
build/
```

`vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify',
  ],
  pwa: {
    workboxOptions: {
      skipWaiting: true,
    },
  },
};
```

Thank you for anyone taking the time to help

Comment: Do you get the same error (`Type alias 'MergeList' circularly references itself.`) if you execute `vue-cli-service test:unit`?

Comment: Yeah, it works wonderful. It only happens when I actually run `npm run serve`

Comment: As a workaround, you can skip `eslint` plugin on serve running: `vue-cli-service serve --skip-plugins @vue/cli-plugin-eslint`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ignorePatterns` in `.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  ignorePatterns: ["**/node_modules/**"] // THIS WORKS!
};
```

Comment: This did not work out-of-the-box for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think `.eslintignore` should be:

```
node_modules
public
bin
build
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but still getting the same error. Only in ts-toolbelt  folder

Comment: Add that to you ignore file then

Comment: Tried adding the folder directly with `node_modules/ts-toolbelt/out/index.d.ts` but still getting the same error in that folder

Comment: What happens if you just delete `.eslintIgnore`?

Comment: the same. Keeps linting eslint anyway

Comment: Try the project on another machine, to rule out something hidden on your box

Comment: I tested in a friend's machine (`npm run dev` and `npm run build`) but both fails

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix this @Charlie?

Comment: @tamj0rd2 No. Still having the same problem. Lost many hours to this problem and ended up staying with the problem